# TF2 - hub.text_embedding_column still to be implemented

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I'm migrating an old TensorFlow 1.x training script and I got some problem with hub.text_embedding_column function. At the moment, the following code does not work

```
# Python 3.6.9
import tensorflow as tf # tf.__version__ 2.1.0
import tensorflow_hub as hub # hub.__version__ 0.7.0

module_spec = hub.load_module_spec('https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4')
text_column = hub.text_embedding_column(key='test_col', module_spec=module_spec)
```

The error that I got is:

> RuntimeError: Missing implementation that supports: loader(*('/tmp/tfhub_modules/29abffb443cb0a0ca9c72e8e3863b76d85028490',), **{})

I tried `help(hub.text_embedding_column)` and the help returns me

> TODO(b/131678043): This does not work yet with TF2.

Do you know any workaround to use text_embedding_column with TF2? I'm able to load the model using `hub.load('https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4')` but then I don't know what to do with it.

Thank you all (:

Answer (score 0):

Following this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/508) I was able to solve my problem, at least for now. It's still based on `tf.compact.v1.placeholder` but at least I can use hub.text_embedding_column.

```
# Python 3.6.9
import tensorflow as tf # tf.__version__ 2.1.0
import tensorflow_hub as hub # hub.__version__ 0.7.0

def build_module_fn(model_url):
    def module_fn():
        text_input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None])
        embed_layer = hub.KerasLayer(
            model_url,
            input_shape=[],  # Expects a tensor of shape [batch_size] as input.
            dtype=tf.string)  # Expects a tf.string input tensor
        embeddings = embed_layer(text_input)
        hub.add_signature(inputs=text_input, outputs=embeddings)
    return module_fn

module_spec = hub.create_module_spec(build_module_fn('https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4'))
hub.text_embedding_column(key='text', module_spec=module_spec)
```

Hope that this can help other people!